# Where to put files for ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS(an not too confident in my skills with the file system in linux) and am trying to make a basic robot to simulate on Gazebo.  I understand that one of the things I need to do is create the robot chassis from a urdf file, along with the nodes to control it etc...  But I'm not entirely sure where to to put these files.  Not just files I would make but packages I would have downloaded where would I extract them to. Would they go in the workspace directory that tutorials had me make in my home directory? Or would they have to go in the gazebo directory which is in the ROS directory which is in the opt directory? Or does it even matter?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55089/where-to-put-files-for-ros/) by [BCT](https://answers.ros.org/users/4179/bct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I put source packages in my ROS workspace. Development of new packages I do in the sandbox. Let the install system manage the files in /opt/ros. So that nothing breaks at an update or gets lost.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-02-13**:
Don't forget to set ROS_WORKSPACE and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environnement variable ('export' command) to ensure your packages can be used with ros commands.

**Comment by [BCT](https://answers.ros.org/users/4179/bct/) on 2013-02-13**:
Thanks for the responses.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by setting ROS environment variables.  As in what are these variables, their function and how I would go about doing this(maybe an example)?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-13**:
Please work through some of the basic ROS tutorials first, then ask additional questions here, if needed. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Tutorials

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-02-14**:
Environment variables are a Unix feature. You can find information about that on any internet Linux-related website. Follow Joq's advice, it will probably give you the information you need.